# How does the .NET CLR distinguish between Managed from Unmanaged Pointers?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, clr

Everything is ultimately JITed into native machine code, so ultimately, we have a native stack in .NET which the GC needs to scan for object pointers whenever it does a garbage collection.

Now, the question is: How does the .NET garbage collector figure out if a pointer to an object inside the GC heap is actually a managed pointer or a random integer that *happens* to have a value that corresponds to a valid address?

Obviously, if it can't distinguish the two, then there can be memory leaks, so I'm wondering how it works. Or -- dare I say it -- does .NET have the potential to leak memory? :O

Comment: I'd love to know why the -1 came along...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the GC knows precisely which fields of every block on the stack and the heap are managed references, because the GC and the jitter know the type of *everything*.

However, your point is well-taken. Imagine an entirely hypothetical world in which there are two kinds of memory management going on *in the same process*. For example, suppose you have an entirely hypothetical program called "InterMothra Chro-Nagava-Sploranator" written in C++ that uses traditional COM-style reference-counted memory management where everything is just a pointer to process memory, and objects are released by invoking a Release method the correct number of times. Suppose Sploranator hypothetically has a scripting language, JabbaScript, that maintains a garbage-collected pool of objects.

Trouble arises when a JabbaScript object has a reference to a non-managed Sploranator object, and that same Sploranator object has a reference right back. That's a circular reference that cannot be broken by the JabbaScript garbage collector, because it doesn't know about the memory layout of the Sploranator object. So there is the potential here for memory leaks.

One way to solve this problem is to rewrite the Sploranator memory manager so that it allocates its objects out of the managed GC pool.

Another way is to use a heuristic; the GC can dedicate a thread of a processor to scan *all of memory* looking for integers that happen to be pointers to its objects. That sounds like a lot, but it can omit pages that are uncommitted, pages in its own managed heap, pages that are known to contain only code, and so on.  The GC can make a guess that if it thinks an object might be dead, and it cannot find any pointer to that object in any memory outside of its control, then the object is almost certainly dead.

The down side of this heuristic is of course that it can be wrong. You might have an integer that accidentally matches a pointer (though that is less likely in 64 bit land). That would extend the lifetime of the object.  But who cares? We are *already* in the situation where circular references can extend the lifetimes of objects. We're trying to make that situation *better*, and this heuristic does so. That it is not perfect is irrelevant; it's better than nothing.

The other way it can be wrong is that Sploranator could have *encoded* the pointer, by, say, flipping all of its bits when storing the value and only flipping it back right before the call. If Sploranator is *actively hostile* to this GC heuristic strategy then it doesn't work.

Resemblance between the garbage collection strategy outlined here and the actual GC strategy of any product is almost entirely coincidental. Eric's musings about implementation details of garbage collectors of hypothetical non-existing products are for entertainment purposes only.

Comment: How did you come up with "InterMothra Chro-Nagava-Sploranator"? That reminded me of Na'vi language :O

Comment: +1 For referring to [JabbaScript](http://www.schnell.net/jabbascript.html) ... how funny.

Comment: Imagine what will happen when the GC will update that integer (that thinks it's a pointer) on heap compacting

Answer (score 4):

The garbage collector doesn't need to *infer* whether a particular byte pattern (whether 4 or 8 bytes) is a pointer or not - it *already* **knows**.

In the CLR everything is strongly typed, so the garbage collector knows whether the bytes are an `int`, a `long`, an object reference, an untyped pointer, etc etc.

The layout of an object in memory is defined at compile type - metadata stored in the assembly gives the type and location of every member of the instance.

The layout of stack frames is similar - the JITter lays out the stack frame when the method is compiled, and keeps track of what kinds of data are stored where. (It's done by the JITter to allow for different optimizations depending on the capabilities of your processor).

When the garbage collector runs, it has access to all this metadata, so it never needs to guess whether a specific bit pattern might be a reference or not.

[Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/) is a good place to find out more - [References are not addresses](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx) would be a place to start.

Comment: So that means the garbage collector not only has to process the data in the stack every time, it also has to process the metadata for it each time as well (because it has to know how to interpret everything)... am I understanding that correctly? Also, is it really that "references are not addresses", or just that "you shouldn't assume references are addresses, even though they really are"? There's a big difference between the two, when the entire question is about what's actually happening internally...

Comment: The garbage collector has to do a *lot* of work - processing the stack, local variables, both value and reference types, and *multiple* heaps; we get away with it because it allows memory allocation to be incredibly cheap. In current versions of the runtime, references do happen to be implemented as addresses, but that's an implementation detail that might change. The key is that the GC *knows* they're references, so it never needs to look at a random bit pattern and guess whether it references an object or not.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Remember, the *jitter* knows the *exact* layout of the stack. It knows precisely which stack locations (and registers) contain managed addresses. The work of that analysis can be done at jit time, and the jitter and the garbage collector can work together to make the GC efficient. The GC certainly does not have to go back to the assembly metadata every time it runs a scavenging pass over a stack frame! All that analysis is already performed.

Comment: I like to think of references as "object ID's"; use of the term avoids confusion with "pass by reference" semantics.  The normal way of passing an object to a function is to pass the object-ID by value.  BTW, if I had my druthers, .net would support an 8-byte 'pseudo-pointer' type which would combine a 4-byte object-ID with a 4-byte offset.  I'm not really sure why object-ID's in 64-bit systems have to be 64 bits; how many programs are going to have to create more than four billion objects?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that all managed memory is managed by the CLR. Any actual managed reference was created by the CLR. It knows what it created and what it didn't.

If you really feel you must know the details of the implementation, then you should read [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) by [Jeffrey Richter](http://www.amazon.com/Jeffrey-Richter/e/B000APH134/). The answer is not simple - it's quote a bit more than can be answered on SO.

Comment: Yes, but I suspect the question relates more to what is *still on use*, especially when considering the stack.

Comment: @John: "It knows"? How? It's not God, so the information has to be somewhere... and the question is, where?

Comment: @Mehrdad: not God, but, like God, it created the references, and so can be expected to keep track of them. You're talking about references to managed memory, which is allocated by - the CLR. The only way to get a reference to managed memory is to get it from the CLR, or from code which got the reference from the CLR.

Comment: @John: That is telling me nothing about the underlying implementation. I'm asking about how it's done *internally*, not how it "seems to work" externally. It's *got* to keep track of things somewhere, and that's what the question is about.

Comment: @John: I'm not sure what I should update -- I think `How does the .NET garbage collector figure out [...]` differs clearly from `What should I know about the .NET GC, and what am I /not/ supposed to know?`... though if you have any specific suggestions for what to write, I'd love to hear them. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: you're right. The problem is that you're thinking of the CLR as something equivalent to the C runtime library. Objects on the C runtime heap might have been allocated from "malloc", or they could be random integers. However, since the CLR is the only thing that can create a managed object, it can keep track of the objects it creates and where the references move to. Remember it's also in charge of JITting IL into native code.

Comment: @John: You're just telling me, using different words, *why* this is possible, but not *how* it's done.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I'm telling you that it doesn't matter exactly how it's done, as that may vary from release to release. I'm telling you the fundamental answer on this: it can be done because the CLR hands out the pointers to begin with.

Comment: @John: Uh... if it didn't matter to me, I wouldn't have asked. Saying "it's none of your business" (in whatever form, even if it's in the form of a euphemism like "abstraction") has a helpfulness of zero. :\

Comment: @Mehrdad: it's not that it's none of your business, it's that it's an implementation detail. Is there a specific implementation you're interested in? .NET vs. Mono? x86 vs x64?

Comment: @John: I already mentioned .NET (and not Mono) in the original question, and I don't really care if it's x86 or x64 -- either is fine, and both is even better. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: which release of .NET?

Comment: @John: Whichever one you or anyone else knows the answer to. And honestly, is that answer *that* implementation-dependent? I don't think so, but if it is, then please let me know how exactly they differ in finding and tracing the GC roots on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Well when JITing the code the compiler knows in which places it puts the reference to objects. Whenever you use a field in a method, which holds a reference, it knows that in that place theres a reference. This information can also be preserved when you JIT the code.

Now a reference points to the object. Each object has a pointer to its class (the .GetType()-method). Basically the GC can now take a pointer, follow it, read the type of the object. The type tells you if there are other fields which contain references to other objects. This way the GC can walk the entire stack and heap.

Of course this is a bit over simplified, but the basic principle. And in the end its a implementation-detail. There are certainly other ways and all kinds of tricks to do this efficiently.

Update after comment: The pointer on the stack points to a object on the heap. Every object has a header, which also contains a pointer to its type-info. So you can dereference the pointer on the stack, there dereference the pointer to the object-info to find out what kind of object it is.

Comment: How does it "know" what kind of object is on the stack... is this info stored somewhere? Where? On the stack?

Comment: @Gamlor: Your update just barely misses the point -- I'm not talking about how the GC interprets what it already knows to be a reference; I'm talking about how it finds out it's a reference in the first place. I know about the type header in the object, but that's independent of the reference itself.

Comment: I think @Bevan explained that a bit better than me. The GC/JIT always know the type of stuff. First on the stack by the layout. It know in which location reference are and in which location other types. On the heap it can read the type-info and infer the memory-layout for that.

Comment: On the heap I get how it works. On the stack, I'm not sure -- wouldn't it slow down the garbage collector if, on every single collection, it had to go through a data structure to find out where to look in the first place? Is that actually what happens?

Comment: I don't know the exact implementation, it's not may area of expertise. I guess in practice there are lot of tricks to avoid walking unnecessary often through tons of data structures.

Comment: Hm... I was hoping for a more detailed answer, but this makes sense; I'll accept it if nothing more detailed shows up. +1 thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new reference type object in .NET you are automatically "registering" it with the CLR and its GC. There is no way to inject random value types into this process. In other words:

The CLR does not maintain some large, disorganized heap of pointers mixed with value types. It just tracks CLR-created objects (for garbage collection purposes anyway.) Any value type will be short-lived on the stack or be a member of a class instance. There is no potential for confusion the GC.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point. How does this relate to interpreting *object references* (**not** value types) on the *stack*?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Garbage Collection: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)
*(Some of the technical details might be a bit dated but the structure described is valid.)*

Some brief points from the article....

> When a process is initialized, the runtime reserves a contiguous
>   region of address space that initially
>   has no storage allocated for it. This
>   address space region is the managed
>   heap. The heap also maintains a
>   pointer, which I'll call the
>   NextObjPtr. This pointer indicates
>   where the next object is to be
>   allocated within the heap. Initially,
>   the NextObjPtr is set to the base
>   address of the reserved address space
>   region.

...

> Every application has a set of roots. Roots identify storage
>   locations, which refer to objects on
>   the managed heap or to objects that
>   are set to null. For example, all the
>   global and static object pointers in
>   an application are considered part of
>   the application's roots. In addition,
>   any local variable/parameter object
>   pointers on a thread's stack are
>   considered part of the application's
>   roots. Finally, any CPU registers
>   containing pointers to objects in the
>   managed heap are also considered part
>   of the application's roots. **The list
>   of active roots is maintained by the
>   just-in-time (JIT) compiler and common
>   language runtime, and is made
>   accessible to the garbage collector's
>   algorithm.**

...

> When the garbage collector starts running, it makes the
>   assumption that all objects in the
>   heap are garbage. In other words, it
>   assumes that none of the application's
>   roots refer to any objects in the
>   heap. Now, the garbage collector
>   starts walking the roots and building
>   a graph of all objects reachable from
>   the roots. For example, the garbage
>   collector may locate a global variable
>   that points to an object in the heap.

On the question...

> ...or a random integer that happens to
>   have a value that corresponds to a
>   valid address?....memory leaks ?

If the object is not reachable the GC will destroy it regardless.

Comment: `The list of active roots is maintained by the just-in-time (JIT) compiler and common language runtime` -- the question is, _where_? It definitely seems like an expensive operation to add some entry to a list every single time a value type with an embedded reference is created on the stack, so how exactly is this done? The description isn't sufficient because it doesn't say how the "list of active roots" actually works.

Comment: Also: `If the object is not reachable the GC will destroy it regardless.` --> The question is about how the GC detects the reachability in the first place? It can't just assume everything is a pointer, because that causes memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the "CLR via C#" book, the runtime knows exactly where will find the references/pointers by inspecting the "method's internal table".
What this internal table holds in the microsoft's implementation is unknown, but it can accuretly identify call frames on the stack, local variables and even what kind of value the registers hold for each EIP address.

The mono implementation used a conservative scanning, which means that treated every value on the stack as potential pointer. That not only translates to memory leaks, but also (since it cannot update those values) the objects identified by this, are treated as pinned (unmovable by the GC compactor) and that leads to memory fragmentation.

Now mono has the option of "Precise Stack Marking" which uses GCMaps. You can read more for it here http://www.mono-project.com/Generational_GC#Precise_Stack_Marking

Note that this implementation is not accurate as it is the MS one, since it continues to treat the current frame conservatively.

Answer (score -1):

References have headers, so it's not just a random integer.

Comment: What are the headers like? (Aren't references only 4 bytes? How can there be a header?) And what if there just *happens* to be a random integer with the right header and the right pointer?

Comment: @Mehrdad: it doesn't matter. It's not possible in .NET to confuse an int with a pointer value. It is possible and a fairly common source of bugs in C/C++ but not in .NET.

Comment: References do not have headers.

Comment: @Paul: "It doesn't matter?" Depends on the person, but to me, it certainly does! Where did you get that idea? .NET is **not** an interpreter; it's a runtime system. As such, it has to work with native machine code in the same way as any other program, so that certainly matters here. @Hans: Yeah, I thought so. I think @Mark was just making an educated guess, but it was wrong here. :)

Comment: Oops, I was thinking of the objects themselves. Anyway thinking about references as addresses is going about it the wrong way anyway: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx

Comment: @Mark: "`Now, behind the scenes, the CLR actually does implement managed object references as addresses to objects owned by the garbage collector, but that is an implementation detail.`" And I'm *asking* about the implementation detail, so the language or CLR specs themselves don't exactly help here...

Comment: The CLR still has the method metadata; it still has the info of what's what on the stack.  It chose how (and whether, vs. registers) to put it there after all.